# SwiftUI Using List and Foreach to iterate through keys in a dictionary and create a list view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to iterate through the keys in my `categories` dictionary and create a list of row views based on the keys. Can anybody take a look at my code below and spot what's wrong with it?  I am not sure what to put in as the parameter in the ForEach loop as well as List. Thanks!

```
struct HomeView: View {
  
    var categories :  [String : [Drummer]] {
        .init(
            grouping: drummerData,
            by: {$0.category.rawValue}
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            List {
                ForEach(categories.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) {key in
                    DrummerRow(categoryName: "\(key)", drummers: self.categories[key]!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is solved according to Wild Child's answer. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0):

List in SwiftUI is the equivalent of UITableView, so a ScrollView is already embedded in. Remove it and your view should render correctly

Comment: Woo it works! Thanks for the help! I forgot List is already scrollable

Comment: Glad it helped. Mark this question as answered and appreciate if you +1 me.